# How to read and write shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

When my data use `shared_ptr` which is shared by a number of entries, any good way to read and write the data to show the sharing? For example

I have a Data structure

```
struct Data
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

Data data;
data.a = 2;
data.b = 2;
```

I can write it out in a file like `data.txt` as

```
2 2
```

and read the file, I can get the `data` with values `a = 2` and `b = 2`. However if the Data uses share_ptr, it becomes difficult. For example,

```
struct Data
{
    shared_ptr<int> a;
    shared_ptr<int> b;
};

Data data;
```

data can be

```
data.a.reset(new int(2));
data.b = data.a;
```

or

```
data.a.reset(new int(2));
data.b.reset(new int(2));
```

The 2 cases are different. How to write the data to the `data.txt` file and then read the file to the data, I can get the same data with the same relations of `a` and `b`?

Comment: ... what do you mean by "read and write the data to show the sharing"? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: You can tell how many `shared_ptr`s are sharing the same resource with the [`use_count()` member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count).

Comment: @MarkGarcia I edit my question to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't any clearer your pointers point to nothing, I can't really think of a reason to have multiple shared ptrs in the same class that point to the same object

Comment: @aaronman Rephrase again. Please help to take a look.

Comment: Sorry all i have is an iphone i could try after i get back to my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of data serialization problem. Here, you want to serialize your `Data` that has pointer types within it. When you serialize pointer values, the data they are pointing to is written somewhere, and the pointers are converted into offsets to the file with the data.

In your case, you can think of the `int` values as being written out right after the object, and the "pointer" values are represented by the number of bytes after the object. So, each `Data` in your file could look like:

```
|total-bytes-of-data|
|offset-a|
|offset-b|
|value[]|
```

If `a` and `b` point to the same instance, they would have the same offset. If `a` and `b` point to different instances, they would have different offsets.

I'll leave as an exercise the problem of detecting and dealing with sharing that happens between different `Data` instances.